# Kinect One calibration using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, kinect, camera-calibration

I’m working on a project with stereo calibration for Kinect one using OpenCV. The CoordinateMapper in the Kinect SDK does not provide sufficent results (speed & quality). The color camera has a full HD resolution (1920x1080 pixel) and the depth/infrared image is 512x424 pixel. My checkerboard is 10x7 with 36mm on an A3-sheet.

I perform the intrinsic calibration with `cv::calibrateCamera` for both cameras separately. The resulting camera and distortion matrix is pretty similar to GML camera calibration. `cv::undistort` returns good visual results applying these parameters. The error is 0.941842 (infrared) and 0.583004 (color)

Next is stereo Calibration using previous intrinsics:

```
cv::Mat rotation, translation, fundamental, essential;
std::cout << "Stereo Error: " << cv::stereoCalibrate(pointsBoard, points1, points2, cameraMatrix1, distortion1, cameraMatrix2, distortion2, imageSize,
        rotation, translation, essential, fundamental, cv::TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER+ CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 100, 1e-5), CV_CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC|CV_CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST) << std::endl;

cv::Mat R1, R2, P1, P2, Q;
cv::Rect validRoi[2];
cv::stereoRectify(cameraMatrix1, distortion1,
    cameraMatrix2, distortion2,
    imageSize, rotation, translation, R1, R2, P1, P2, Q,
    cv::CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY, 1, imageSize, &validRoi[0], &validRoi[1]);

cv::initUndistortRectifyMap(cameraMatrix1, distortion1, R1, P1, imageSize, CV_16SC2, rmap[0][0], rmap[0][7]);
cv::initUndistortRectifyMap(cameraMatrix2, distortion2, R2, P2, imageSize, CV_16SC2, rmap[1][0], rmap[1][8]);
```

I create the map for undistortion and rectifing only one time during calibration. The translation in pixel is calculated by `cv::remap` one calibration image, again searching for checkerboard and calculating the average translation in X since both images should match on height and width?! The stereo is 0.412727 and reprojection error is 0.715183 using only images with checkerboard parallel to camera (growing on different positions/angles). Calibration image remapping and translation looks ok.

In live mode both images are remaped and translated so that they should match:

```
//overlay images
// recitfy
cv::remap(depth1, depth2, rmap[0][0], rmap[0][13], cv::INTER_LINEAR);
cv::remap(color1, color2, rmap[1][0], rmap[1][14], cv::INTER_LINEAR);

// translation and crop
depth1 = depth2(cv::Rect(750, 380, imagesOutputSize.width, imagesOutputSize.height)).clone();
color1 = color2(cv::Rect(750+translationX, 380, imagesOutputSize.width, imagesOutputSize.height)).clone();
```

The result is pretty bad :(

- [remaped depth](http://i59.tinypic.com/21m6ka0.png)
- [remaped color](http://i60.tinypic.com/2qx8gt0.png)

Comment: Some more images (intrinsics/undistortion): http://i61.tinypic.com/ml5rmd.png, http://i60.tinypic.com/35ic6x3.png, http://i61.tinypic.com/10p6qkp.png, http://i59.tinypic.com/2zi3pr5.png, http://i58.tinypic.com/2zyzx5e.png, http://i57.tinypic.com/2qbhdoy.png

Comment: Some more images (extrinsics, after calibration): http://i62.tinypic.com/2hekaid.png, http://i57.tinypic.com/1191izk.png, http://i60.tinypic.com/5vxg2e.jpg, http://i61.tinypic.com/2qbyyhd.jpg

Comment: Finale images (remaped, cropped and translated- LIVE) http://i60.tinypic.com/yi98x.png http://i60.tinypic.com/2cig0ao.png